# Is there any way in CodeIgniter to remove dbprefix from the query?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm building a CI application, and I need to use 2 different databases (mysql & mssql). When i try to run a simple query to the mssql DB then CI adds the dbprefix to the table names, so it ends up to an error. How is it possible to prevent CI adding the prefix? There is no dbprefix set in database.php file

Query in Model

```
    public function getAccName($uid) 

{
            $this->load->database('mssqlsrv',TRUE);

           return $this->db->where("uid", $uid)
    ->select("account")->get("user_account");                  
}
```

Comment: Did you try $this->db->set_dbprefix(''); $this->db->dbprefix('users') ?

Comment: Yes, I did try this but it didn't work. let's say I want to execute select * from users  the query builder trys to execute DBPREFIX.users  table. it doesn't exist so the query fails

Comment: But you configured both databases in database.php and set $db['mssqldbname']['pconnect'] = FALSE; ? pconnect has to be set to FALSE for both to make sure it works. Then it should just work without the commands above.

Comment: yes both of them are configured in database.php and pconnect is false. It adds the name of mysql database as a prefix for the tables for the mysql database. tried your example too. same behavior

Comment: Can you please add your query to the question? Thanks.

Comment: There we go. You can't just use $this->db with multiple databases. You have to assign the connection to a variable like $db1 and then $db1->where etc. See https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/connecting.html for more information. Tell me if it worked :)

Comment: It did work. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer this correctly:

When working with multiple database connections in Codeigniter each connection needs to be assigned to a variable like:

```
$DB1 = $this->load->database('mssqlsrv', TRUE);
$DB2 = $this->load->database('group_two', TRUE);
```

Then you can do the query with

```
$DB1->where("uid", $uid)->select("account")->get("user_account");
```

instead of

```
$this->db->where("uid", $uid)->select("account")->get("user_account");
```

See https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/connecting.html for more information on this.

Answer (score 0):

How about trying to set each database connection to a certain variable:

like below code:

```
$mysqlConn = $this->load->database('mysql', TRUE);
$mssqlConn = $this->load->database('mssqlsrv', TRUE);
```

then try to use them for your query, for the code above it should be:

```
public function getAccName($uid) 

{
   $mssqlConn = $this->load->database('mssqlsrv', TRUE);

    return $mssqlConn->where("uid", $uid)
    ->select("account")->get("user_account");                  
}
```